# What to do after the looker bureau

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I finished the looker bureau and there is nothing to do is there anything else to do
And I have completed the elite four and the looker bureau

Answer (score 6):

I found this a long time ago on Tumblr. I do not have a source to credit, and this is not my list. But it has a lot of things to do in pokemon XY after you have finished the game.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider breeding competitive and or shiny pokemon or you can just wait until Pokemon Omega Ruby and Alpha Sapphire come out next month and play your heart out on them.

Answer (score 0):

After the original game, Shauna will come to your house and ask if you would like to trade Pokémon, the Pokémon will be the starter whatever your starter is strong against. After you trade Pokémon and beat the Elite Four, Zapdos, Moltres, and Articuno will show up on random routes, depending on what starter you chose.

- Articuno: Chespin
- Moltres: Froakie
- Zapdos: Fenniken

Then, you can complete the Pokédex. Once you complete the Pokédex, Professor Sycamore will give you a shiny something... and this will increase your chances of finding a shiny and beating everyone in the game and on the internet in battle.

Answer (score -1):

Wonder trade... Battle spot... Talk to every freaking person in the game... Try to get all the mega stones.